# Define a global function within a namespace class

Tags: php

Im trying to define a global function within a namespaced class.

if I define the function within the method 'setupSystem', this gets created as MyProject\TestFunction()

i've tried using namespace { ... } to escape the current "MyProject" namespace, but end up getting a syntax error.

below is a sample of the code. Any ideas how i can define the global function?

Thanks!

*namespaced.php*

```
namespace MyProject;

use \Mobile_Detect as Mobi_Detect;
class Mobile_Detector
{
     private function setupSystem(){

        if ( !(function_exists('\cc_isMobile') || !function_exists('\cc_is_Tablet'))) {


            global $cc_detect;
            // DECLARING MOBILE CLASS INTO VARIABLE
            $cc_detect = new Mobi_Detect();

            /***** Check Global Functions ***********/

            namespace {
                if( !(function_exists('cc_isMobile'))){
                    function cc_isMobile() {
                        global $cc_detect;
                        return $cc_detect->isMobile();
                    }
                }
                if( !(function_exists('cc_isTablet'))){
                    function cc_isTablet() {
                        global $cc_detect;
                        return $cc_detect->isTablet();
                    }
                }
                if( !(function_exists('cc_isIOS'))){
                    function cc_isIOS() {
                        global $cc_detect;
                        return $cc_detect->isiOS();
                    }
                }
                if( !(function_exists('cc_isDROID'))){
                    function cc_isDROID() {
                        global $cc_detect;
                        return $cc_detect->isAndroidOS();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _..trying to define a global function within a namespaced class..._ Why? Isn't this just what classes don't want to be?

Comment: ahh. well previous coder had lots of spotty code. Slowly updating code, but trying to make sure previous setup still works..

Comment: You can't. Why on earth do you think you need to do this?

Comment: well.. a wordpress theme was created, and within the theme files they created their functions and would call them randomly. Problem is that these were not hooked. I'm currently transitioning them into plugins.. but there are sooooooo many files, so I need to set these up to cover those random calls until i fully clean everything...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't nest namespace and that's why you have syntax error. Because you don't have code with working function `MyProject\TestFunction`, I paste example what is proper use of multiple namespace in one file.

```
namespace MyProject {

    use \Mobile_Detect as Mobi_Detect;

    class Mobile_Detector
    {
        private function setupSystem()
        {
            if (!(function_exists('\cc_isMobile') || !function_exists('\cc_is_Tablet'))) {

                global $cc_detect;
                // DECLARING MOBILE CLASS INTO VARIABLE
                $cc_detect = new Mobi_Detect();
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace {
    function TestFunction() {
        return MyProject\TestFunction();
    }
}

namespace { // it may be included in previous namespace block, but I want to separate execution of this function
    var_dump(TestFunction());
}
```